# Test element height using Selenium IDE

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide

I have some Selenium tests I've been building with the Firefox IDE plugin. This is the first I've attempted tests like this, the client asked for it, as I'm refactoring some code and they want to be certain things still work.

I have an element that resizes via a script, and I need to test its height. My Selenium source currently looks something like:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/landing-page</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.facebook.</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I need to test that an element is greater than a certain height. How do I write that in after clicking on the `.facebook` link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a vanilla way of doing such a thing. You'd have to create your own javascript plugin to put into the IDE.  Learn how to structure a javascript  plugin for the IDE, then you can put something like this into it (mind you this is pseudo-code):

```
function validateHeight(HTMLElement element, int height) {
  return assertTrue(element.height == height);
}
```

Comment: Sound like the right path, do you have any preferred resources on this for someone who's never really worked with test before?

Comment: As an avid user of Selenium WebDriver, not so much RC or IDE, i do have one recommendation... Ditch IDE. if you are intending for this selenium project to be worth something in the long run, then i recommend using a solution like the [getting started with selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) project (which is Java). Either way, migrate to Selenium WebDriver.  If you are intending to keep with the IDE, then i think http://adam.goucher.ca/?p=1348 should help

Comment: I could go either way on the IDE vs WebDriver, I'll give WebDriver a look thanks!

Comment: well, there are clear cut definitions on what you want.  take a look at [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/JTLHvax.png), you can see that they both have their different uses.